# What does the root locus tell us exactly?

Tags: control, stability, root-locus

More specifically what information can one extract from a root locus drawing without calculating the transfer function and then using Routh Hurwitz or other techniques? Essentially, what information does the Root Locus alone give us?

Comment: [Take your pick](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+does+the+root+locus+tell+us+exactly&rlz=1C1ONGR_en-GBGB999GB999&oq=What+does+the+root+locus+tell+us+exactly&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1232j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Root Locus shows you how the zeros and the poles of your system change when you change a parameter. This is very useful to study and modify the behavior of your system by adjusting that parameter.

For example, converting a high order system to a lower order one by changing its gain.
Root locus, can help us in the design by selecting the operation point (that yield the required characteristics) on the root locus. If there will be more than two poles in the system, the dominant poles will be of interest.

In this example, you can see how for different values of gain K you can choose the behavior of the system from unstable to stable, looking only to the position of the poles in te RL. "[Reference](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Root-locus-plots-of-a-continuous-model-with-a-delay-of-T-015-s-as-approximated-by-a_fig9_277722689)"

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Root-locus-plots-of-a-continuous-model-with-a-delay-of-T-015-s-as-approximated-by-a_fig9_277722689]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As @andy-aka pointed out, Google has some answers to this. I found this page very illustrative, you might want to take a look at it. [link](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Root_Locus/RootLocusWhy.html#:~:text=The%20root%20locus%20plot%20indicates,will%20give%20us%20good%20results)